# Is this syntax is correct?

Tags: vba, excel

```
a = 2    

k = 35

j = 3


For Each Cell In Range(Cells((k + 1), j), Cells((k + 1), (a + (j - 1))))

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(k, (j + 1)).Value = a Then

        Cell.Value = m

    Else

        Cell.Value = Sheets("LAP " & (a - 1)).Cells((k + 1), j).Value

    End If

Next Cell
```

[image: IMG1]

Comment: You seem not to define `m` anywhere. And all variables are not updated inside the loop, hence `If ActiveSheet.Cells(k, (j + 1)).Value = a Then` would always check range D35 and return the same result. You may give more details about your goal

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is generally ok, but I would like to point out some risks and issues with it:

1. Always use `Option Explicit`: while not useful at first, it can save you lot of headache in the future. It makes you declare your variables before using them, which lead us to:
2. Always declare your variables, like this: `Dim a As Long, j As Long, k As Long`.
3. As your loop variable, you use `Cell`, the name is meaningful and good, but VBA might reserve that name for some other purpose and it will lead to a name conflict.